# I'm trying to figure out whats wrong with the following json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong with the following json data, i'm currently using http://jsonlint.com/ to validate it which keeps failing with;

Parse error on line 9:

```
...3"        }    ]}
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

The code is as follows;

```
{
    "Count": [
        {
            "EBOOTHS": "1492",
            "BRANDS": "439",
            "CATEGORIES": "503"
        }
    ]
}
```

many thanks!

Comment: That validates fine for me. Is there whitespace after the last character?

Comment: Try this. {Count: [{"EBOOTHS": "1492","BRANDS": "439","CATEGORIES": "503"}]}

Comment: `Count` needs to be in quotes @ArpitSingh

Comment: I understand, just thought maybe he was trying to create a namedArray and mistakenly confused it with JSON

Comment: Validation works fine btw on jsonlint

Answer (score 0):

when I copy paste your code directly into jsonlint.com it validates. Are you sure you don't have extra lines somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I went to http://jsonlint.com and pasted in your code. I saw the following:

Results

> Valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

EOF means the validating expects end of file/code. Therefore you have an invalid character after the last }. Maybe this char is invisible, like CR/LF or TAB. How do you create this json?